# Activity Monitor Showing Long Duration for WAITFOR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using Activity Monitor, I am consistently seeing the following query showing an average duration of over 300 seconds:

```
WAITFOR(RECEIVE conversation_handle, service_contract_name, message_type_name, message_body 
                FROM ExternalMailQueue INTO @msgs), TIMEOUT @rec_timeout
```

There don't seem to be any adverse effects on the server, and this query is showing zeros for all other columns.

Is this normal or a cause for concern?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? I am facing the same issue in my environment and working on it so please let me know what steps you finally took to solve this.

Comment: @AnkitShah apparently according to the checkmark below he implemented Mark's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Service Broker process listening to a queue for messages. 300 seconds will be the time out specified in @rec_timeout. See [RECEIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963.aspx) reference in books online.

Comment: Correct. Just to add: `ExternalMailQueue` is the [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx) notifications queue that signals the mail processor that it has work to do.